# How to authorize users for rest service

Tags: authentication, rest, client

me and my friend are doing a project for a company. It involves getting some information from the database and display it on a smartglass device (epson, sony, ...). Now we want to build a RESTful service where the glass can get it's data from. The question is, how i can secure this service, because i don't want it to be accessible from anywhere besides from the glasses. My solution would be to implement some kind of whitelist on the server where the MAC-address from each glass device (like 3-10 in the whole company) is stored. What do you think would my best bet be?

Comment: Is this on an internal, closed network or the internet as a whole?

Comment: Question will be, how will you get an MAC over HTTP/HTTPS? Only thing is you'll have to install some form of application on your device which exposes it, so you can send it off to RESTful services, but that would be easily spoofed though.

Comment: You are developing a client app on the smartglass too?

Comment: maybe use a morse code winking sequence as a password

Comment: This question gets asked here in a slightly different form every [expletive] week. You can't control the client.